# auto-complete needed in javascript added textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

In the code below the auto-complete is working as it is supposed to in the textarea. But it does not work in the added textarea upon click on button +procedure

1. I need the auto-complete to work on all textarea added using the button. How can I do it?
2. Right now the auto-complete is case sensitive. How do I make the auto-complete to happen regardless of CASE?

   HTML:

   ```
   <div id="p_procedures">
         <textarea rows=5 cols=50>
   </textarea>
   </div><a href="#" id="addProcd">+ Procedure</a>
   ```

JS:

```
  $('textarea').textcomplete([{
  match: /(^|\s)(\w{2,})$/,
  search: function (term, callback) {
    var words = ['google', 'facebook', 'GITHUB', 'microsoft', 'yahoo'];
    callback($.map(words, function (word) {
        return word.indexOf(term) === 0 ? word : null;
    }));
 },
replace: function (word) {
    return word + ' ';
}
}]);


 var procdDiv = $('#p_procedures');
 var i = $('#p_equipments p').size() + 2;



  $('#addProcd').on('click', function(){
        var t ='<textarea rows=5 cols=50></textarea>';
        $(t).appendTo(procdDiv);

        p++;
        return false;
    });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adhly/mqxv8vn3/24/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a new element:

```
$(t).appendTo(procdDiv);
```

Initializing the auto-complete plugin would be exactly like it is with any other element:

```
$(t).textcomplete({ ...options... });
```

Rather than copy/paste the entire initialization, you might extract it into a function that can be invoked where needed and you'd supply that function with the target element(s).  Or even just put the plugin options in a variable:

```
var textCompleteOptions = [{
  match: /(^|\s)(\w{2,})$/,
  search: function (term, callback) {
    var words = ['google', 'facebook', 'GITHUB', 'microsoft', 'yahoo'];
    callback($.map(words, function (word) {
        return word.indexOf(term) === 0 ? word : null;
    }));
  },
  replace: function (word) {
    return word + ' ';
  }
}];
```

Then just call it repeatedly with those options:

```
$('textarea').textcomplete(textCompleteOptions);
```

and later...

```
$(t).textcomplete(textCompleteOptions);
```

The point, though, is that any time you want to initialize the plugin on a given `textarea` you need to invoke the plugin initializer.  jQuery isn't going to do that for you.

Comment: To expand on the answer's comment at the end:  when you call `$('textarea').textcomplete` - it applies to all `textarea`s that exist *at the time the call is made*.  If you then *add* another `textarea`, it hasn't had the `.textcomplete` call made against it so you need to call `.textcomplete` against each *new* element after adding it.

Comment: Thank you @David and freedomn-m This solves my first question. How do I make the auto-complete to appear regardless of CASE?

Answer (score 1):

Solves The Case-Sensitive issue here

```
search: function (term, callback) {
var words = ['google', 'facebook', 'GITHUB', 'microsoft', 'yahoo'];
callback($.map(words, function (word) {
    return word.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) === 0 ? word : null;
}));
```